# Repeated Measures ANOVA with two covariates

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss, ancova

I am doing a repeated measures Anova
My variables are like this:
Y - continues variable measured pre and post intervention
Intervention - the between group variable with three levels in which participants were randomly assigned to.
M - I want to check for two continues covariates (both measured only before the intervention) (I want to see whether they have an effect on the score changes of y pre and post intervention)

Initially I was interested in whether I should conduct a repeated measures ancova with both M as covariates? Or should I do one model for each?
Secondly if I have one of my covariate variables as significant what does it mean? I am not sure how to interpret the interaction.

Thank you very much for your help, I am relatively new in stats and I am a bit unsure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV! I would put both covariates into the same model. Are you going to use covariates as main effects or put in some type of group x covariate or time x covariate interaction?

Comment: Thank you for your response :) I want to check whether the difference in score from point one to point two is explained by the covariate. In SPSS when I do this the interaction I get is between my dependent variable and the covariate. Is this okay?

Comment: OK I checked and to the best of my understanding, what you are describing is actually correct for what you want. So, the interaction will tell you whether your covariate affects your pre-post change :)

Comment: Okay got it! Thank you very much for your thorough help!